# Having problem recording screen in DotA 2

Tags: dota-2, recording

Maybe this question doesn't belong here, but please bear with me.

I'm unable to record screen using camtasia. The software just records audio not the video. I've tried every option in the recorder, also included -noborder in the launch options to start DotA 2 as a borderless window. And I don't wanna use FRAPS, camtasia is very advanced and I like it. If anyone has tried screencasting using camtasia please help me point out how to do this.

Comment: Semi-related, but OBS is better in just about every way.

Comment: OBS is good at streaming right (Open broadcaster software)? I do not think it can be compared to camtasia, it saved me a bunch of times when every other program failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBS is better for streaming purposes not for recording.  camtasia is definitely better for recording. But if you still want to stick with camtasia what you have to do is this:

1. start dota 2 and go to screen settings (accessed from top left settings area)
2. set the screen to borderless windowed mode.
3. set an optimal resolution of your liking
4. have fun recording. :)

Comment: I did try turning it into borderless windowed mode. Didn't work

Comment: No problem. Glad to of been helpful.